# Unable to understand merge common ancestor output and reason of conflict

Tags: git, rebase, merge-base

I have a branch feature based on my develop branch.
My feature was needed earlier than anticipated in production so I decided to rebase my feature branch on top of my master branch like this (my feature branch has only one commit):

```
git checkout feature
git rebase --onto origin/master HEAD~
```

During the rebase, I encountered a conflict, here displayed with diff3 output format:

```
<<<<<<< origin/master
||||||| merged common ancestors
some code I didn't touch
=======
same code I didn't touch
code I added in my commit on feature
>>>>>>>
```

I did not expect to have a conflict, since I only added some code and did not modify the existing one. Moreover, the "code I didn't touch" was on my feature branch based on develop but not in my commit and not in origin/master either, so I do not understand how it can appear in the merged common ancestor part.

When I run `git merge-base --all HEAD origin/master` it displays the last commit on origin/master, that does not have the "code I didn't touch".

To me the output of the rebase should have been something like this, yielding no conflicts (of course there would be no conflict output then, but just to show what I was expecting):

```
<<<<<<< origin/master
||||||| merged common ancestors
=======
code I added in feature
>>>>>>>
```

The code I didn't touch should not appear anywhere since it is not on origin/master nor in my commit.
I thought the rebase onto command I did would have the same result as cherry-picking my feature's only commit on top of origin/master (which will be the case once I resolve the conflict).

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What a commit is

> The code I didn't touch should not appear anywhere since it is not on origin/master nor in my commit.

It *is* in your commit. You may be thinking incorrectly about what a commit is. It is *not a diff*. Commits are not *changes*. A commit is a snapshot of your entire project — all the files, in their current state. So if the parent of `feature` had this code, and you didn't touch that code when you created the commit that is now `feature`, then yes, that code is most certainly in that commit, because for it not to be there, you would have had to delete it, and you did not.

#### What you did

Switching to cherry-pick won't change anything; `rebase` *is* `cherry-pick`.

So let's run with that, and treat what you did as a cherry-pick. We will say that you cherry-picked the last commit of `feature` — that is, the commit pointed to by the branch name `feature`, itself — onto `origin/main`. (The only actual difference in this case between `rebase` and `cherry-pick` is what happens to the branch name pointers afterward, and we aren't going to consider that at all in what follows, so it's irrelevant.)

#### How cherry-pick / rebase works

A cherry-pick is a merge, meaning that its job is to create a brand new commit, although the commit it creates is a normal commit, not a merge commit (that is, it has just one parent). The new commit is created using *merge logic*, using the parent of the cherry-picked commit as the merge base. (If you don't understand what I just said, read my https://www.biteinteractive.com/understanding-git-merge/.)

Therefore, when you cherry-pick the last commit of `feature` onto `origin/main`, you are saying to Git:

- Think about the diff from the parent of `feature` to `feature`.
- Think about the diff from the parent of `feature` to `origin/main`.
- Enact *both* those diffs as applied to the parent of `feature`, and make a commit expressing that, whose parent is `origin/main`.

Very well. What are those diffs?

- From the parent of `feature` to `feature`, some code was added adjacent to `oldcode`.
- From the parent of `feature` to `origin/main`, that same `oldcode` was *deleted*.

That, I think, is the part that surprises people. You seem to imagine that `origin/main` has no contribution to make here. But it does. The cherry-pick requires, among other things, that we be somehow able get *from* the parent of `feature` *to* `origin/main`. That can be quite an elaborate operation — and for that very reason, merge conflicts are *very common* when cherry-picking (including rebasing).

#### The conflict

So let's think about what each diff does with respect to `oldcode` in the parent of `feature`. `feature` added to it. `origin/main` deleted it. Thus you are asking Git both to add to the hunk and to delete the hunk. Those are contradictory instructions, so Git asks you what to do.

Resolving the conflict is very, very easy; this is probably the easiest and most common case of a merge conflict. You know what you want; you either want `origin/main` to have both `oldcode` and the new code, or you want it to have just the new code. But Git *doesn't* know what you want, so this still counts as a merge conflict, which merely means that you have to do a little manual editing yourself. Do it, don't worry, be happy, and move on.

#### A corollary

Since the part that probably surprises you the most is the contribution of `origin/main` as a *deleter* of the code, let me enact a little drama for you. We start with this:

```
* 31da420 (HEAD -> mybranch) myotherfile
* 0ec170a myfile
| * 7dcb9af (main) emptied myfile
| * 7e2b31f myfile
|/  
* 61bc628 start
```

Here's what happened so far since `start`.

- On `main`, we added a file `myfile` with contents `hello`, and then we edited `myfile` to be empty.
- On `mybranch`, we also added a file `myfile` with contents `hello`, and then we added another file, `myotherfile`.

Now rebase / cherry-pick just the last commit of `mybranch` onto `main`. What will the state of `myfile` be in the newly created commit? *It will be emptied*. That's because, from the point of view `0ec170a`, the contribution of `7dcb9af` was to empty `myfile`. From the point of view of `0ec170a`, the other commit `31da420` did not contradict that in any way.

So you see, even if you had *not* added the new code, the fate of `oldcode` ("code I didn't touch") would not have been what you expect. You think it would have been left alone. It would not have been. It would have been deleted.

Comment: Very thorough answer, thanks.
There is still one thing I don't get: how is the common ancestor made, in my case and in your corollary ? Because when I ran `git merge-base --all HEAD origin/main` it showed the last commit on main, that did not have the `oldcode`. This `oldcode` was also never a part of main, just a part of the develop branch. I just don't understand how git can display that the common ancestor contains `oldcode` whether this `oldcode` had been emptied in main or was simply never in it. Or maybe the common ancestor is not the commit displayed by git merge-base ?

Comment: The merge base is for when you are going to say `git merge`. That's not the same as when you say `git cherry-pick` or `git rebase`; in that case, the merge base is the parent of commit that is to be copied, as I've already said. Indeed, the results from doing `git merge` would be very different, for exactly that reason; the merge base is different, so that the diffs we have to form embrace the _whole histories_ of the two branches from the point there they diverged. But `cherry-pick` is forced surgery, with surprising results, as I've demonstrated.